# How to restart a program in terminal periodically?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, terminal, automation

I am calling a program, let say `myprogram`, from the terminal (in OS X Mavericks) but some times it gets stuck due to external problems out of my control. This tends to happen approximately every half an hour.

`myprogram` basically has to perform a large quantity of small subtasks, which are saved in a file that is read in every new execution, so there is no need to recompute everything from the beginning.

I would like to fully automatize the restarting of the program by killing and restarting it again, in the following way:

1. Start the program.
2. Kill it after 30 minutes (the program will be probably stuck).
3. Restart it (back to step 1).

Any ideas on how to do this? My knowledge of bash scripting is not great precisely...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script can serve as a wrapper script for `myprogram`

```
#!/bin/bash
while true                        #begin infinite loop (you'll have to manually kill)
do
  ./myprogram &                   #execute myprogram and background
  PID=$!                          #get PID of myprogram
  sleep 1800                      #sleep 30 minutes (30m might work as parameter)
  kill -9 $PID                    #kill myprogram
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a wrapper, but, an infinite loop **is** **not** an optimal solution. If you are looking to relaunch a program on timer, or not, depending on the exit code and are on OS X, you should use `launchd` configuration (xml property list) files and load them with `launchctl`.

```
 KeepAlive <boolean or dictionary of stuff>
 This optional key is used to control whether your job is to be kept continuously running or to let
 demand and conditions control the invocation. The default is false and therefore only demand will start
 the job. The value may be set to true to unconditionally keep the job alive. Alternatively, a dictio-nary dictionary
 nary of conditions may be specified to selectively control whether launchd keeps a job alive or not. If
 multiple keys are provided, launchd ORs them, thus providing maximum flexibility to the job to refine
 the logic and stall if necessary. If launchd finds no reason to restart the job, it falls back on
 demand based invocation.  Jobs that exit quickly and frequently when configured to be kept alive will
 be throttled to converve system resources.

       SuccessfulExit <boolean>
       If true, the job will be restarted as long as the program exits and with an exit status of zero.
       If false, the job will be restarted in the inverse condition.  This key implies that "RunAtLoad"
       is set to true, since the job needs to run at least once before we can get an exit status.
```

...

```
ExitTimeOut <integer>
     The amount of time launchd waits before sending a SIGKILL signal. The default value is 20 seconds. The
     value zero is interpreted as infinity.
```

For more information on launchd & plists visit :

1. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html
2. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html